# Template parameter pack expansion without arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

I'm working on understanding template parameter pack expansion in C++. For demo purposes, I wanted to write a function that prints human readable names of types used in a signature (any signature - that's where the variadic template comes in).

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
std::string SignatureToString()
{
  return std::string();
}

template<typename Arg1, typename... Args> 
std::string SignatureToString(const Arg1&, Args&&... args)
{
  std::string strRetVal = boost::typeindex::type_id<Arg1>().pretty_name();
  std::string strRemainingSignature = SignatureToString(args...);          // expanding parameters works
  if (!strRemainingSignature.empty())
  {
    strRetVal = strRetVal + ", " + strRemainingSignature;
  }
  return strRetVal;
}

class cDog {/* ... */};

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
  int i(0);
  std::string str;
  //cDog someDog("Harry"); // don't want to construct this dummy object!
  std::cout << "GetSignature(): '" << SignatureToString() << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GetSignature(int): '" << SignatureToString(i) << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GetSignature(std::string): '" << SignatureToString(str) << "'" << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "GetSignature(cDog): '" << SignatureToString(someDog) << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GetSignature(int, std::string): '" << SignatureToString(i, str) << "'" << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "GetSignature(int, std::string, cDog): '" << SignatureToString(i, str, someDog) << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

The above example works. Since boost::typeindex::type_id does not really need the passed variable of type Arg1 (and some types - such as cDog - might not or not easily be dummy-constructable), I thought I could change the implementation to the one below (same template arguments, but no passed parameter pack of those types) and recursively call the template by expanding the pack of **types** instead of the pack of **parameters**. I read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack section "Template argument lists" to mean that this should be possible, but my compiler (vc141) gives me error C2672 (no matching signature found).

edit: The error description apparently has to do with template resolution, but I don't see the applicability to my problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2672?view=msvc-150

```
template<typename Arg1, typename... Args> 
std::string SignatureToString()
{
  std::string strRetVal = boost::typeindex::type_id<Arg1>().pretty_name(); // this line apparently still works (makes sense)
  std::string strRemainingSignature = SignatureToString<Args...>();        // expanding type pack does not work (...?)
  if (!strRemainingSignature.empty())
  {
    strRetVal = strRetVal + ", " + strRemainingSignature;
  }
  return strRetVal;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
  std::cout << "GetSignature(): '" << SignatureToString() << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GetSignature(int): '" << SignatureToString<int>() << "'" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "GetSignature(std::string): '" << SignatureToString<std::string>() << "'" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the stop condition of the recursion.
To stop the recursion you use

```
std::string SignatureToString()
```

In the first example you call it like

```
SignatureToString();
```

While in the second one you call it like

```
SignatureToString<>();
```

Which does not work since it’s not a template.

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++17 you can use `if constexpr` and [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). It's so much better than recursive function templates.

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
std::string SignatureToString()
{
    std::string ret;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 0) {
        ret = "";
    }  else  {
        ret = ((boost::typeindex::type_id<Args>().pretty_name() + ", ") + ... );
    }
    return ret.substr(0, ret.size()-2);
}
```

Comment: Not quite, you repeat the delimiter (which should be `", "` after the last element

Comment: Good catch! Edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As the other Daniel pointed out, the problem is stopping the recursion. The following is not really pretty, but it works.

```
// Catch call with zero args
std::string SignatureToString()
{
  return std::string();
}

// Catch call with exactly one arg
template <typename Arg1>
std::string SignatureToString()
{
  return boost::typeindex::type_id<Arg1>().pretty_name();
}

// Catch all other cases
template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Args>
std::string SignatureToString()
{
  std::string strRetVal = boost::typeindex::type_id<Arg1>().pretty_name();
  std::string strRemainingSignature = SignatureToString<Arg2, Args...>();
  if (!strRemainingSignature.empty())
  {
    strRetVal = strRetVal + ", " + strRemainingSignature;
  }
  return strRetVal;
}
```

Comment: Another way to do it is to use a template `struct` instead of a template function. Then you can actually write a `<>` specialization.